# How to have different custom message in Social Sharing for Phonegap ?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, socialshare

How to have different custom message in Social Sharing for Phonegap ? 
Not for the button click, I need it in the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I created a sample project and uploaded in github for your social sharing requirement via popup in Ionic framework and the reference for the link is [social sharing](https://github.com/anilkumar007/social-share) , Please have a look at README.md file for step by step procedure
Having any queries reply

Comment: I searched it at many places, the thing that I require to do it not possible. Thanks though.

Comment: This is possible only if we use individual social apps.